# Cargar 2 ArrayList en un JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo éste método que en teoría carga dos ArrayList en un JTable

```
public void CargarJTbable() {
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            modelo.addColumn("ID");
            modelo.addColumn("RUT");
            modelo.addColumn("NOMBRE");
            modelo.addColumn("APELLIDO");
            modelo.addColumn("TELEFONO");
            modelo.addColumn("TALLER");

            for (PersonaDTO pers : p.leerPersonaTodos()) {
                Object[] fila = new Object[5];
                fila[0] = pers.getId();
                fila[1] = pers.getRut();
                fila[2] = pers.getNombre();
                fila[3] = pers.getApellido();
                fila[4] = pers.getTelefono();

                modelo.addRow(fila);
            }

            for (TallerDTO tall : t.leerTallerTodos()){
                Object[] fila = new Object[1];
                fila[0] = tall.getNombre();

                modelo.addRow(fila);
            }

            tbl_datos.setModel(modelo);

        }
```

[image]

En teoría los últimos 3 datos deberían estar insertos en "Taller"

Me podrían ayudar a encontrar la lógica para poner los datos de la lista "t.leerTallerTodos()" y añadirlos a "Taller
EDIT: Intenté cargarlo en el campo 5 pero me arroja un error, adjunto img.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDIT 2: Ahora que cambié el código

```
Object[] fila = new Object[6];
fila[5] = tall.getNombre();
```

Me carga en "Taller" pero más abajo, debería comenzar desde arriba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería quedar así. El último campo está vacío porque esa persona no está asociada a un taller. Lo edité manualmente pero no logro hacerlo automático desde el código :(

Comment: Los últimos 3 que te mete en ID los estás metiendo en fila[0], no deberías meterlos en fila[5]?

Comment: Revisa la edición

Comment: es porque haces Object[] fila = new Object[5] (así sólo puedes acceder a las posiciones 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 )y tendrías que hacer Object[] fila = new Object[6]; así podrás acceder a la posición fila[5];

Comment: Referente a eso lo había hecho, pero me cargaba más abajo. Hice otro edit con otra imágen

Comment: Algo hemos avanzado ¿Cómo debería de quedar? Si tienes que quedar a la par de los usuarios los tienes que cargar a la vez que los usuarios. Cuando creas las filas con los datos del usuario, tienes que rellenar su posición 5 con ese dato, sino siempre te quedará abajo ya que estás creando una fila nueva

Comment: El campo taller debería quedar a la par, desde arriba.
Sucede que las listas vienen de dos consultas SQL a dos tablas diferentes

Comment: genera una imagen de cómo debería quedar, se entenderá bien lo que quieres llegar a obtener

Comment: Hice el último edit

Comment: Es lo que te he dicho, cuando añadas los usuarios, por cada usuario tienes que añadirle el taller, por ejemplo, para el primero sería: fila[0] = pers.getId();
                fila[1] = pers.getRut();
                fila[2] = pers.getNombre();
                fila[3] = pers.getApellido();
                fila[4] = pers.getTelefono(); fila[5] = "Alfareras"

Comment: Así te lo hará, pero para hacerlo bien, tendrás que combinar los 2 arrays para hacerlo automático

Comment: Lo óptimo sería tener un array con los usuarios y su trabajo, o sea, cpombinar los arrays antes de generar la tabla, así ya no tendrás ningún problema

Comment: Sucede que estoy aprendiendo a usar patrón de diseño DAO y la relacion de Persona y Taller es muchos a muchos, por lo tanto tengo una 3era tabla. A la cual yo podría hacer un select que me arroje una lista única. Pero me compliqué en donde poner esa consulta...

Comment: Puedes generar el campo Taller en el objeto persona y rellenarlo, con eso podrías hacerlo fácil pero es más sencillo configurar la BD para que te arrastre esos datos al hacer la consulta y ya lo tendrías también

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que estás agregando filas nuevas con el método ***addRow***. Al tener dos ***for*** separados, es por eso que se agregan las filas debajo y no como un campo mas al final de cada registro.
Te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
List<TallerDTO> tallerDTOS = t.leerTallerTodos();
int posicionColeccionTaller = 0;
for (PersonaDTO pers : p.leerPersonaTodos()) {
  Object[] fila = new Object[6];
  fila[0] = pers.getId();
  fila[1] = pers.getRut();
  fila[2] = pers.getNombre();
  fila[3] = pers.getApellido();
  fila[4] = pers.getTelefono();
  if (posicionColeccionTaller < tallerDTOS.size()) {
    fila[5] = tallerDTOS.get(posicionColeccionTaller).getNombre();
    posicionColeccionTaller++;
  }
  modelo.addRow(fila);
}
```

NOTA: estoy asumiendo que se retorna una lista al ejecutar ***leerTallerTodos()***

Para tener una mejor respuesta y aún más específica necesitaría conocer un poco más las estructuras.

Saludos y espero que te ayude.